# How to avoid print a line in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am working with a script that prints something similar to that:

```
Foo text1
Bar text2
Bar list text3
...
Foo text4
Bar text5
Bar list text6
...
```

I am only interested in the `Foo` and `Bar` lines, but not in the `Bar list` ones. I have been searching information for doing this with grep, awk or sed, but I always print the line `Bar list text3`. There is a solution that consists in save the output in a file and then removing the line using sed, but I was wondering if there is a way to do that without saving the output in a file.

Comment: And with a single edit, you have **completely** changed the question, invalidating all answers already given.

Comment: You say it hasn't worked with `grep` but don't say what you have tried which is standard to do on SO. For example, I'm pretty sure `grep -v "Bar list"` would do it.

Comment: `sed '/^Bar list/d' file` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -v -F "Bar list" <filename>
```

With the `-v` option, `grep` lists only lines **not** matching the pattern.

With the `-F` option, you tell `grep` that the "pattern" is not a pattern at all, but a fixed string.

Comment: I decided to downvote the question rather than answering it because OP didn't even say what he/she tried with grep. But fair from you to answer so +1.

Comment: Besides, i would guess that `grep -v` would be a duplicate of another question.

Comment: @ThibaultD. It is 100% a duplicate

Comment: @Thibault: `grep -v` 91,402 results

Comment: I'm looking for a dupe ATM. You find one, I happily vote-for-close. ;-)

Comment: Not saying you shouldn't answer; OP could've bothered searching.

Answer (score 2):

head is the most straightforward way. In case you want to learn something about sed or awk:

```
awk 'NR<3' file
```

or

```
sed '1,2!d' file
```

for `head`:

```
head -n2 file
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider also add the starightforward way just in case others will see this and want to use it.

Comment: Or for a pure Bash solution: `IFS= read -r line1; IFS= read -r line2; printf '%s\n' "$line1" "$line2"` or similar stuff with `mapfile`.

Comment: I have updated the post. I forgot to say that it prints more lines in that way

Comment: 2q is more efficient for sed

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^(Foo|Bar)\s+\S+\s*$/!d' file
```

If it doesn't start with `Foo` or `Bar` and have one other non-space pattern then delete the line.